# how to detect if the current time is between 15.31 - 15.45

Tags: asp.net, datetime

in dot net frame work 2

how to better this and easy to used i have many times

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string timenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        Label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
        Label2.Text = getTimeZone(timenow);
    }

    //hh:mm:ss
    protected string getTimeZone(string time)
    {
        string[] e = time.Split(':');
        int h = Convert.ToInt16(e[0]);
        int m = Convert.ToInt16(e[1]);
        int s = Convert.ToInt16(e[2]);

        if ((h == 15) && (m >= 1) && (m <= 30) && (s <= 59))
        {
            return "15.01 - 15.30";
        }
        if ((h == 15) && (m >= 31) && (m <= 45) && (s <= 59))
        {
            return "15.31 - 15.45";
        }
        if ((h == 15) && (m >= 46) && (m == 0) && (s <= 59))
        {
            return "15.31 - 15.45";
        }

        return time;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the logic of the last if... That would never occur because (m >= 46) && (m == 0) will never be true...
Should it be 
if ( ((h == 15) && (m >= 46)) || ((h == 16) && (m == 0))  )
{
      return "15.46 - 16.00";        }

Comment: You don't need to check on (s <= 59) as seconds are allways from 0 to 59.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 15, 31, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 15, 45, 0);

if (now >= start && now <= end)
    Console.WriteLine("We have a go!");
```

Comment: If you want the pattern for the minutes span to apply for all hours in a day, this will result in a lot of if statements...

Comment: Not really, you just get into TimeSpans and the like, or use your own solution. The point was more that you can compare DateTime's directly, and you *should*, not parse them to strings, then parse out the strings to integers and fiddle around like that.

Comment: I agree that you should not go via string parsing to int and fiddle around. Your answer was making a good point about that. I provided an answer that takes out the different parts directly from the DateTime object, and checks against the minutes part of it. This way it works also for any hour in the day. Of course, this only works if the minute pattern is same for all hours...

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
    Label2.Text = getTimeZone(timenow);
}

//hh:mm:ss
protected string getTimeZone(DateTime time)
{
    if (time.Hour == 15 && time.Minute >= 1 && time.Minute <= 30)
        return "15.01 - 15.30";
    if (time.Hour == 15 && time.Minute >= 31 && time.Minute <= 45)
        return "15.31 - 15.45";
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using string instead of DateTime directly, you can use DateTime.TimeofDay

Answer (score 1):

This would work if same pattern for all hours:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
    Label1.Text = timenow.ToString("T");        
    Label3.Text = timenow.ToString("D");        
    Label2.Text = getTimeZone(timenow);         
}

//hh:mm:ss
protected string getTimeZone(DateTime time)
{
    if (time.Minute >= 1 && time.Minute <= 30)
        return String.Format("{0:00}.01 - {0:00}.30", time.Hour);
    if (time.Minute >= 31 && time.Minute <= 45)
        return String.Format("{0:00}.31 - {0:00}.45", time.Hour);
    if (time.Minute >= 46)
        return String.Format("{0:00}.46 - {1:00}.00", time.Hour, (time.Hour < 23) ?  time.Hour+1 : 0);
    if (time.Minute == 00)
        return String.Format("{0:00}.46 - {1:00}.00", (time.Hour > 0) ? time.Hour-1 : 23, time.Hour);
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd take getTimeZone out of the page class and put it in a util class for a start...

Comment: Get it to work first, and then consider to make it available in other scenarios by exposing it in a utiliy class.

Comment: Well, it sounds like it is working already, he just wants a bettwe way of doing it. He says he has used it many times, so I assume this code is all over the place at the moment.  Putting it in util class will help him when he's refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the strings to DateTime objects and compare them.
You also you use string.CompareTo() to compare the strings directly.

Comment: No need to even do that, since he's starting with DateTime objects and calling ToString on them...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    Label1.Text = now.ToString("T");
    Label3.Text = now.ToString("D");

    if (now.Hour == 15 && now.Minute >= 1 && now.Minute <= 30)
        Label2.Text = "15.01 - 15.30";
    else if (now.Hour == 15 && now.Minute >= 31 && now.Minute <= 45)
        Label2.Text = "15.31 - 15.45";
    else
        Label2.Text = now.ToString("T");
}
```